# How to auto-upload photos to Website when posting on Instagram

Tags: file-upload, upload, web, instagram

Is there any way to auto-aupload photos to my website, when they are published on Instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Instagram API to check for new content and upload to your website:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Since you need to access only your content, you dont need to get reviewed by Instagram, you will have access to latest 20 images using API in sandbox mode, write script on your server to check for API once a day and update your website.